# How to declar UITableViewController in Unwind segue from UITableViewController to UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have my main view and a RoutinesTableViewController.

I wanted to unwind back to my man VC and tried this:

```
@IBAction func selectRoutine(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    let RoutinesTableViewController = segue.sourceViewController as RoutinesTableViewController
    if let selectedRoutine = RoutinesTableViewController.selectedRoutine {
        RoutineLabel.titleLabel = routine.valueForKey("name") as? String
    }
}
```

I got an error in

```
    let RoutinesTableViewController = segue.sourceViewController as RoutinesTableViewController
```

**Use of undeclared type RoutinesTableViewController **

But the above is definitely a UITableViewController class and controller

Is the segue.sourceViewController only for UIViewControllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line

```
let RoutinesTableViewController =
```

you are assigning to a class.  Perhaps you meant

```
let routinesTableViewController =
```

Comment: No way!!! if the constant name clashes with the UITableViewController name it will think I'm assigning the class?

Comment: In iOS, it is good practice to only capitalize types.  Did you try running it with a lowercase name?

Comment: and yea it works thats why the "no way" pretty surprised

Comment: thank you very much. You just took one hour of frustration away, in minutes

Comment: I have another question but I can't post it yet. Its one I had several times but could never understand it.

Comment: Sure what is it?  Do you need to fly me to Berlin to help out? :) :)

Comment: Haha I'm leaving Berlin soon. Heading back to Toronto for the meantime

Comment: I'll post my problem as an answer here and delete it once you respond to it

Comment: Lucky!  I need a break from LA

Comment: LA sounds like a cool place. I do recommend travelling europe though, you learn a great deal. if you got passive or mobile income, you could do it too. thats what I plan to do. trade stocks and travel the world

Comment: I lived in London for a year up until the olympics.  But it feels like ages ago.

Comment: London is a fun place. would actually enjoy living there. But looks like you need another adventure :)